# Leetcode 191 - number of 1 bits - Easy Problem

Tags: string, count, hashmap, char, bit

**Question:** Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and return the number of '1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).

**Example Input:** 00000000000000000000000000001011.
**Output:** 3
**Explanation**: The input binary string 00000000000000000000000000001011 has a total of three '1' bits.

**My approach:**
public class Solution

{

```
public int hammingWeight(int n)
{
    int i=0;
    String s = Integer.toString(n);
    HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
    while(i<s.length())
    {
        if(hm.containsKey(hm.get(i)))
            hm.put(s.charAt(i),hm.get(i)+1);
        else
            hm.put(s.charAt(i),1);
        i+=1;
    }
    return hm.get('1');
}
```

}

**My input:** 1011

**My output:** 1

**Expected correct output :** 3

I don't understand why this hashmap solution for counting number of 1's is not working. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i = 0;
HashMap<Character,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
while(i<s.length())
{
   if(hm.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))
       hm.put(s.charAt(i),hm.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
   else
       hm.put(s.charAt(i),1);
   i+=1;
}

// System.out.println(hm.get('1'));

for (Map.Entry entry : hm.entrySet()) { 
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + " Value: " + entry.getValue()); 
        }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note-** You need to consider below points:

1. Replace `if(hm.containsKey(hm.get(i)))` with `if(hm.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))` as key should refers to character of `ith` index of input string.
2. Replace `hm.put(s.charAt(i),hm.get(i)+1);` with `hm.put(s.charAt(i),hm.get(s.charAt(i))+1);`as we first get value of `ith` index from hashmap and then increment it.